# Defining many Angular directives with loops

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a bunch of Angular directives that all look the same, like (a more complex version of)

```
app.directive('note', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="' + 'note' + '"></div>
    }
});
```

with `note` replaced by many other things. I want to define them all in a loop to stay DRY. I tried

```
var dirs = ['note', 'introduction', 'thing'];

for (var dir, i = 0; dir = dirs[i]; i++) {
    app.directive(dir, function () { ... });
}
```

to no avail. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: A directive is really intended to be a self contained, reusable component. I'd suggest that the Angular team and most Angular developers would suggest what you are trying to do is a terrible idea. DRY is a rule of thumb, not an immutable law of physics.

Comment: Why the strange condition in the loop? why not just use the length of the array and i like usual?  I've seen this done for a couple of components (using something similar actually for a generic "social-media-icons" thing where it automatically pulls the right icon and makes a link, it's not exactly the same since I'm using attributes but let me see if it will help here... I've also seen this technique for facebook plugin wrappers in angularjs.

Comment: @shaunhusain When i == dirs.length, dir = undefined, and the loop stops. Since we're using angular anyway, I prefer angular.forEach

Comment: @jtseng yeah I get that it will still work, just generally seen while loops done with this kind of condition and it seems unnecessarily confusing to use this when a for loop checking a length condition is clear and works perfectly well.

Comment: @shaunhusain It was confusing at first, but I think I prefer this over having the iteration variable all over the place. If I am stuck with having an iteration variable, I would prefer it to be all in one place, preferably hidden from me.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? It looks identical, so perhaps there's something else you're not doing right :)

Comment: @Jack I have no idea. It was my understanding that Angular's `forEach` was essentially a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should do this. You should instead, pass the value into the directive. However, if you really feel like you need to do it, it does work fine: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NnkeP/2/).

HTML:

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">

        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
          Hello, {{name}}!
        </div>
        <introduction> </introduction>
        <note></note>
        <thing></thing>
        <notAThing></notAThing>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    var dirs = ['note', 'introduction', 'thing'];

    angular.forEach(dirs, function(dir) {
        myApp.directive(dir, function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                template: '<div class="' + dir + '">something</div>'
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: My first instinct was to pass the value to a directive, but ultimately I'd like my view to read like a more structured document, and `<note>You should probably read carefully</note>` looks better than `<div data-type='note'>You should probably read carefully</div>`. Then again I'm relatively new to Angular. Does the benefit to readability outweigh the 'unnaturalness' to looping over directive creation or not?

Comment: @jclancy Well, creating new elements *is* one of the most special features about Angular. After seeing your example, I take back what I said about passing in values. I think I like your way of doing it better.

Answer (score 0):

I gotta say this may be the noob in me talking but I don't really see a major problem with this if you know what you're doing:

```
(function() {
  var createDirective, module, pluginName, _i, _len, _ref;

  module = angular.module('FacebookPluginDirectives', []);

  createDirective = function(name) {
    return module.directive(name, function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
          return typeof FB !== "undefined" && FB !== null ? FB.XFBML.parse(element.parent()[0]) : void 0;
        }
      };
    });
  };

  _ref = ['fbActivity', 'fbComments', 'fbFacepile', 'fbLike', 'fbLikeBox', 'fbLiveStream', 'fbLoginButton', 'fbName', 'fbProfilePic', 'fbRecommendations'];
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    pluginName = _ref[_i];
    createDirective(pluginName);
  }

}).call(this);
```

^ this is not my code btw just something I picked up and has worked for me.  The way this works out is if you have the class set to any of the values in the array then it will attempt to have the facebook javascript parse the node/element.

Comment: What is `this` in this instance? `window`?

Comment: Well this whole block of code is inside it's own JS file and isn't wrapped in anything else "this refers to the global object" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this  Yes you're correct

Comment: Ah, thank you. So indeed, `window` (or I guess in node it would be `process`).

Comment: I think if I were you in this case I would stick with just using classes on the divs to represent what they are instead of making custom tags for everything.  This way (using classes) you can have multiple ones associated with a div if you want to tweak one in particular cases.  Also the ease of readability won't be greatly affected I don't think.  With older IE you have to do createElement for each one you make up too if you plan to use restrict:'E'